# EXCEL: adding records using macro /duplicate records added

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Excel 2019 running adding data records (I'm not a programmer, but this should be easy enough if the DATA ENTRY FORM function from older excel version was not taken out)
I've created a data input sheet to update a running database (on another sheet)
created a macro sub that add's the initial record
When I need to add the next record, it replaces the previous record and adds duplicate record.

I'm able to create the 1st record with success.  adding the next distinct record is where I am failing.

Code below is revised from research:[VBA Entering userform data at next blank row correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783783/vba-entering-userform-data-at-next-blank-row-correctly/27784016)

My macro as follows:

```
Sub UpdateComplaintsTest()

' UpdateComplaintTest Macro

    Set ws = Sheets("ACH Complaints 2019")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B3" 'Inserts the Date Col A
    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B4" 'Inserts Time Col B
    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B5" 'Inserts Name of Complainant Col C
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B6" 'Sender's Contact No Col D
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B7" 'Sender's Email Col E
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B8" 'Date of Transaction Col F
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B9" 'Time of Transaction Col G
    ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B10" 'Transaction Ref No Col H
    ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B11" 'Mode of Tran / Online/Mobile Col I
    ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B12" 'Name of Clearing House Col J
    ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B13" 'Sending Bank Col K
    ws.Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B14" 'Receiving Bank Col L
    ws.Range("L" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B15" 'Amount Col M
    ws.Range("M" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B16" 'Receiver Name Col N
    ws.Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B17" ' Receiver Contact No Col O
    ws.Range("O" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B18" 'Receiver Email Col P
    ws.Range("P" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B19" 'Receiver AccountNo Col Q
    ws.Range("Q" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B20" 'History of Trans Col R
    ws.Range("R" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B21" 'Action 1 Col S
    ws.Range("S" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B22" 'Action 2 Col T
    ws.Range("T" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = "=ACHComplaintsForm!B23" 'Action 3 Col U

End Sub
```

Expected Result:  additional entries from the data input sheet should CREATE a new record on the next row.

Comment: Welcome to **SO**, What is your issue ? Please be more specific than "Fail"

Comment: @Dorian FAIL - the record that is supposed to be updated ERASES the previous record and add 2 records of the current input from the data input sheet.

Comment: You need to save workbook before you do the operation again

Comment: I added a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58102306/11167163) this is quite simple but i think it can solve your issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possibly simple transposition**

Assuming that you add new userform data into an extra form sheet's right most *wandering* column and you just want to write the collected data back **horizontally** to a target sheet, you could use the following approach via `Application.Transpose` in order to interchange rows and column(s) of an intermediate `formdata` array.

```
 Option Explicit                 ' declaration head of Code module

 Sub UpdateComplaintsTest()

    ' [1] assign vertical data column to 2-dimensioned 1-based array formdata
          Dim formdata()         As Variant
          formdata = getFormData("ACHComplaintsForm")    
    ' [2] write data horizontally (i.e. transpose data column from variant array formdata)                                            
          nextTargetRange("ACH Complaints 2019", UBound(formdata), "A").Value = Application.Transpose(formdata)

End Sub
```

**Helper function `getFormData()` called by section `[1]`**

It's possible to assign an entire range to a variant array by one code line, 
e.g. via `formdata = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("XY").Range("B3:Z1000").Value`.
As the right assignment part in section `[1]` gets executed by the following function calculating the most right values in the form data sheet, you are coding `formdata = getFormData("ACHComplaintsForm")` instead.

Furthermore the function resizes the returned data range to 1 column, i.e. the most right column in source data `ACHComplaintsForm` (where the sheet name is passed as a string argument and the starting row defaulting to 3 can be indicated optionally).

```
Function getFormData(ByVal DataSheet As String, Optional ByVal StartRow As Long = 3) As Variant()
' Purpose: return 2-dim 1-based array containing latest data column (i.e. most right column)
' Note:    Function assumes data start at 3rd row
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DataSheet)
        '[a] define number of most right column
             Dim nextCol As Long
             nextCol = .Cells(StartRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        '[b] define number of items in this data column
             Dim Itemscount  As Long
             Itemscount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, nextCol).End(xlUp).Row - StartRow + 1

        '[c] return column data as variant 2-dim 1-based array
             getFormData = .Cells(StartRow, nextCol).Resize(Itemscount, 1).Value
             'Debug.Print "Form Data Range " & .Cells(StartRow, nextCol).Resize(Itemscount, 1).Address
    End With

End Function
```

**Helper function `nextTargetRange()` called by section `[2]`**

This function simply resizes the target row range to the necessary size to receive the indicated number of source items.

```
Function nextTargetRange(ByVal TargetSheet As String, Itemscount As Long, Optional ByVal StartCol As String = "A") As Range
' Purpose: return next free row range to receive needed data starting at a given column
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet)
    ' [a] define next free row
          Dim nextFreeRow As Long
          nextFreeRow = .Range(StartCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' [b] return function result, i.e. the receiving target range
          Set nextTargetRange = .Range(StartCol & nextFreeRow).Resize(1, Itemscount)
          'Debug.Print "Target Range " & nextTarget.Address
  End With
End Function
```

Comment: Let me try this and will get back if this solves the problem... Thank you.

Comment: Yey!!  its working now.  Thanks T.M.  Just a small issue:  New records are added to Row 23 instead of next "null" row. do you think its the way I formatted my target sheet?

Comment: Fine it's working. - What do you mean by "null" row?, Maybe you could give an example - @CarmelaPama

Comment: Macro working!  I used your suggested code, but also did a message box to check if record is being added to the next free row.  I also found out that you need to run the macro while on the database worksheet. Else it will look for the NEXTFREEROW of the Data Entry Sheet